# create a click dropdown box

Tags: jquery, html, css

i would like to know how to create a click to dropdown menu. i want to click on drop and then the menu appears. i can get the rollover which is easy but how can i click to make it appear instead and then disappear when i click outside. kinda like facebook news feed option. here is my code

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#menu{margin:0; padding:0}
#menu ul{margin:0; padding:0; line-height:20px;}/*dropdown*/
#menu li{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;float:left; position:relative;}
#menu ul li a{text-align:center; fot-family:"arial"; text-docoration-none;      height:30px; width:150px; display:block; color:#333fff}
#menu ul ul{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}
#menu ul li:hover ul{visibility:visible}
/*---highlight list has i rollover it--*/
#menu  ul li:hover ul li:hover {background:#ccc}
</style>
</head>


<div id="wrapper" style="backgroud-color:blue">

<div id="menu">
<ul >
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Drop</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link 1</a>
<li><a href="#">link 2</a>
<li><a href="#">link 3</a>
</ul><!--end inner ul -->
</li><!--end main li -->
</ul><!--end main ul -->
</div><!--end menu ul -->
</div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Updated the jsFiddle ...

You will need some JavaScript code to get it.
See that **jsfiddle**: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aW3mw/1/)

**Basically**:

Your HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" style="backgroud-color:blue">

  <div id="menu">
    <ul >
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="drop-menu" >Drop</a>
        <ul id="menu1">
          <li><a href="#">link 1</a>
          <li><a href="#">link 2</a>
          <li><a href="#">link 3</a>
        </ul><!--end inner ul -->
      </li><!--end main li -->
    </ul><!--end main ul -->
  </div><!--end menu ul -->
</div>
```

Your CSS

```
#menu{margin:0; padding:0}
#menu ul{margin:0; padding:0; line-height:20px;}/*dropdown*/
#menu li{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;float:left; position:relative;}
#menu  ul li a{text-align:center; fot-family:"arial"; text-docoration-none;       height:30px; width:150px; display:block; color:#333fff}
#menu ul ul{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}

/*---highlight list has i rollover it--*/
#menu  ul li:hover ul li:hover {background:#ccc}

.visible {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Your JS (with jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    $('#drop-menu').bind('click', function(){
         $('#menu1').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```